# Spring MVC Image not Displayed

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am creating a Spring MVC project . In JSP page I want to display Image. I tried two days but cannot display image in it.  I checked in browser source code , no mater what I do image is not found (404). I have attached screen shot of  my project structure and the Exception.enter image description here

my picture folder is under the parent folder. Everything os working just the image is not being displayed.

Answer (score 3):

In spring you have to map the image folder in dispatcher-servlet.xml file like below.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/img/**" location="WEB-INF/img/" />
```